# Check if string appears in any column (except 1st one) of a data.table

Tags: r, list, data.table

Based on a data.table, DT, with m string columns, how can flag rows in which a string, let's say "BlaBla" appears in at least one column?

What I want is:

```
DT[, flag_BlaBLa:=(test if "BlaBLa" appears in any column except the first one)]
```

I do not want to make explicit reference to column names. Rather I need to refer to col 2 to the max col number in DT (perhaps: `2:ncol(DT)`). Why not? In reality, I have a list of data.frames, with varying number of columns in each. I need to create the flag, as indicated above, for all the data.frames in the list

Edit1: adding a reproducible example. 
Edit2: changing some 'BlaBLa' strings to 'BlaBLa+something'. This should also be matched considered a match as they include 'BlaBLa'.

DT starts with cols `a,b,c` and I want a script to create the `flag_BlaBLa`. Final result would be:

```
DT <- data.table(a=c("x","y","z",'w'),
                 b=c('BlaBLa','BLe','Bli','BlaBLaSometing'), 
                 c=c('Bla','BLe','BlaBLa','Blo'), 
                 flag_BlaBLa=c(T,F,T,T)
                 )
```

For the list, the final result should be:

```
DT1 <- data.table(a=c("x","y","z",'w'),
                 b=c('BlaBLa','BLe','Bli','BlaBLaSomething'), 
                 c=c('Bla','BLe','BlaBLa','Blo'), 
                 flag_BlaBLa=c(T,F,T,T)
                 )

DT2 <- data.table(a=c("q","j","p"),
                 b=c('BLe','Bli','BlaBLa'), 
                 flag_BlaBLa=c(F,F,T)
                 )
l <- list(DT1,DT2)
```

Comment: you can perhaps create a key of all the column values concatenated by some separator, excluding the first column. Then search for the string in the key.

Comment: @samkart, that is a good idea. But how can I create this concatenated var without explicit mention to col names, just the col range `2:ncol(DT)`?

Comment: `DT[, key_ := do.call(paste, c(.SD, sep = "_")), .SDcols = 2:ncol(DT)]`. This might help you in creating a key, excluding the first column.

Comment: @samkart, Nice, tks. This works. Then I did `DT[, flag_BlaBLa := key_ %>%  str_detect('BlaBLa')]` And got the correct result. No I need do these two steps to every element of the list `l`. Do you know how? In any case, please add the answer in these two comments as an answer

Comment: you can use a for loop to iterate over your list `l`. `for (DTbl  in l){ code }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could loop over the list , select the columns and check if there is atleast one "BlaBLa" in any row and mark the row `TRUE`/`FALSE`.

```
library(data.table)
lapply(l, function(x) x[, flag_BlaBLa := rowSums(x[,2:ncol(x)] == "BlaBLa") > 0])


l
#[[1]]
#   a      b      c flag_BlaBLa
#1: x BlaBLa    Bla        TRUE
#2: y    BLe    BLe       FALSE
#3: z    Bli BlaBLa        TRUE
#4: w BlaBLa    Blo        TRUE

#[[2]]
#   a      b flag_BlaBLa
#1: q    BLe       FALSE
#2: j    Bli       FALSE
#3: p BlaBLa        TRUE
```

---

**EDIT**

If it's not an exact match and we need to find a pattern of that string we can need to loop over the columns as well (similar to @MichaelChirico) before taking `rowSums`

```
lapply(l, function(x) x[, flag_BlaBLa := rowSums(sapply(x[, 2:ncol(x)],
                      grepl, pattern = 'BlaBLa', fixed = TRUE)) > 0])


#[[1]]
#   a               b      c flag_BlaBLa
#1: x          BlaBLa    Bla        TRUE
#2: y             BLe    BLe       FALSE
#3: z             Bli BlaBLa        TRUE
#4: w BlaBLaSomething    Blo        TRUE

#[[2]]
#   a      b flag_BlaBLa
#1: q    BLe       FALSE
#2: j    Bli       FALSE
#3: p BlaBLa        TRUE
```

Comment: this is nice and concise. But the variables I am researching on can have more than just the work. "*BlaBLa*" also counts (my initial example should have reflected this possibility). So where the code above has "==" there should be some form of regular expression.

Comment: See `%like%` operator

Comment: @LucasMation do you mean you can have other variations of "BlaBLa" or other words? Do you want an exact match of different words or patterns of matches?

Comment: @RonakShah, "BlaBLa" needs to be part of the strings. See updated example above.

Comment: @LucasMation Updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

We can specify the columns of interest in `.SDcols`, loop through the Subset of data.table (`.SD`) check if it is equal 'BlaBLa', `Reduce` it to single logical `vector` to create the column

```
library(data.table)
lapply(l, function(x) x[, flag_BlaBLa := Reduce(`|`, lapply(.SD, `==`, 
           "BlaBLa")), .SDcols = 2:ncol(x)][])
#[[1]]
#   a      b      c flag_BlaBLa
#1: x BlaBLa    Bla        TRUE
#2: y    BLe    BLe       FALSE
#3: z    Bli BlaBLa        TRUE
#4: w BlaBLa    Blo        TRUE

#[[2]]
#   a      b flag_BlaBLa
#1: q    BLe       FALSE
#2: j    Bli       FALSE
#3: p BlaBLa        TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach with `.SDcols`

```
require(dplyr)
require(data.table)
require(stringr)

DT <- DT[, key_ := do.call(paste, c(.SD, sep = "_")), .SDcols = 2:ncol(DT)]
DT <- DT[, has_blabla := as.integer(str_detect(key_, "BlaBla"))]
```

The first creates a key with all column values per row separated by '_'. Then the next searches it and flags as binary. The search returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`, which when coerced to integer is binary.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `for` loop over the list and `sapply` over the columns, using `.SDcols` to exclude the first:

```
for (ii in seq_along(l)) {
  l[[ii]][ , .SDcols = -1L, 
          flag_BlaBLa := any(sapply(.SD, grepl, pattern = 'BlaBLa', fixed = TRUE))] 
}
```

Note that since you're not actually using any regular expression, `fixed = TRUE` is the more efficient option for using `grepl`. Drop `fixed = TRUE` if the pattern you're trying to detect is indeed a regular expression.

If not all of your columns are string columns, this could be made more efficient by making `.SDcols` more strict, e.g.

```
.SDcols = intersect(2:ncols(l[[ii]]), which(sapply(l[[ii]], is.character)))
```

(or possibly using `is.character(x) || is.factor(x)`)